# Will css be applied in this particular scenario?

Tags: html, css, image, styles

Please forgive my ignorance to all things front-end development - but I was wondering if I have a style that targets images, for example, and then after an arbitrary amount of time a user inserts an image into a content editor (i.e. the image is introduced to the page a long time after the page has been rendered) - will the css style apply to this image? Or is it 'too late'?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - my post is clear enough - will css be applied even to newly added content of a page?

Comment: @SVS When I load something onto my page with AJAX it gets CSS, just as everything what already was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try loading some content with AJAX what should have styles applied. Those *will* be applied.

***But:*** As @BoltClock pointed out, some older IE-versions don't like this, I suggest you take his comment into account.

Comment: As always, older versions of IE are known to have trouble with that, but the bugs are vanishingly rare and probably won't affect day-to-day frontend development. Besides that, this answer pretty much sums it up.